# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'

Tags: android, eclipse

i programed with eclipse but i try make project today that eclipse make errors.
solution that told all is for android studio.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuVNS.png)

Comment: Remove values-v23 folder and then try building the application.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your target sdk version to 23.

Reason : you may be using support design library (v23.z.z) which is dependent on the sdk version 23

Comment: thank you.my sdk version is 23.1.how to change it to23

Comment: your target sdk version is 23.1? are you sure?